# Xml Output from Webservice Add a Xml Element C#

Tags: c#, xml, web-services

I have a webservice that is working without a problem (asmx running in iis). The only problem is that the client is really strict with the XML output. The current format is the following:

```
<ArrayOfVenda xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://213.63.189.121/webservicenos">
<venda>
<id>x</id>
<contact_moment>x</contact_moment>
</venda>
<venda>
<id>y</id>
<contact_moment>y</contact_moment>
</venda>
</ArrayOfVenda>
```

And it should be:

```
<ArrayOfVenda xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://213.63.189.121/webservicenos">
<root>
<venda>
<id>x</id>
<contact_moment>x</contact_moment>
</venda>
<venda>
<id>y</id>
<contact_moment>y</contact_moment>
</venda>
</root>
</ArrayOfVenda>
```

So the only thing is adding a XMLElement with the name root that contains the list venda. I'm having trouble in adding this element tho i really don't know how to go about it in my code. Here it is:

```
[WebMethod]
[return: System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("venda")]

    public List<venda> getListaVendas(string dt_min, string dt_max)
    {
    List<venda> objVendaList = new List<venda>();

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=server;Initial Catalog=db;User ID=user;password=password"))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM dbo.vcnosadesoes_getlistavendas where contact_moment >='" + dt_min + "' AND contact_moment <DATEADD(dd, 1, '" + dt_max + "')", con))
            {
                con.Open();
                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                   var objVenda = new venda();  
                    objVenda.id = dr["id"].ToString();
                    objVenda.contact_moment = dr["contact_moment"].ToString();
                    objVenda.nome = dr["nome"].ToString();
                    objVenda.pacote = dr["pacote"].ToString();
                    objVenda.telefone = dr["telefone"].ToString();
                    objVenda.codigo_wc = dr["codigo_wc"].ToString();                   
                    objVendaList.Add(objVenda);
                }                   
                dr.Close();
            }
        }
        return objVendaList;
    }
```

Any ideas what is the best method to add this element?

PS: I KNOW. I have to change the SQL Query because of SQL Injections i will get to that before putting it live don't worry. Also this Line:

```
[return: System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("venda")]
```

may be doing nothing i just put it up for some tests and never comment it out.

UPDATE : So the script from the client is still returning the error. After hours looking at the debugger i discovered what it need is this output:

```
<root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://213.63.189.121/webservicenos">
<venda>
<id>x</id>
<contact_moment>x</contact_moment>
</venda>
<venda>
<id>y</id>
<contact_moment>y</contact_moment>
</venda>
</root>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the XML has an extra level of testing (the `<root>` element between `<ArrayOfVenda>` and `<venda>`) the c# types you return have to have a similar structure to be successfully serialized in that form.  Thus, introduce a new root type `ArrayOfVenda`:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "ArrayOfVenda", Namespace = "http://213.63.189.121/webservicenos")]
public class ArrayOfVenda
{
    [XmlArray("root")]
    [XmlArrayItem("venda")]
    public List<venda> VendaList { get; set; }
}
```

And return that from your `getListaVendas` method:

```
    public ArrayOfVenda getListaVendas(string dt_min, string dt_max)
    {
        List<venda> objVendaList = new List<venda>();

        // Fill in objVendaList as you do currently

        return new ArrayOfVenda { VendaList = objVendaList };
    }
```

**Update**

Given your new requirements for your XML output, you can define your `ArrayOfVenda` class as follows:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "root", Namespace = "http://213.63.189.121/webservicenos")]
public class ArrayOfVenda
{
    [XmlElement("venda")]
    public List<venda> VendaList { get; set; }
}
```

[`[XmlRoot(...)]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlrootattribute.aspx) defines the name and namespace of `ArrayOfVenda` when it is the root XML element.  [`[XmlElement("venda")]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute.aspx) indicates that the `VendaList` will be formatted without an outer container element, and that each item is to be named `<venda>`.

Comment: Also if i wanted to add to the output the header:


     <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>


Is there any way to add that? (this is not a big deal just checking)

Comment: Yes i fixed already. I noticed tho that it's returning me 

    <ArrayofVenda>
    <root>
    <venda>







.<ArrayofVenda> is not needed and it's making the validation fail. Can i supress this value in the xml output'?

Comment: @MiguelPecegueiro - *`<ArrayofVenda>` is not needed and it's making the validation fail.*  Of course this is possible, but in your question you specifically required this to be present.  Are you changing your question?

Comment: Hum yes i guess. The script that the client provide us is failing to validate the xml output because of that element

Comment: done i updated so the error on my question is that i asked to add the root element on the original code when what it was needed was to replate the ArrayOfVenda with root.